# how to run 10 process and montring it

Tags: nginx, monitoring, ffmpeg, background-process, rtmp

i have about 10-15 FFmpeg Process 
for streaming server like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://ip/play/a03i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv "rtmp://ip:80/APP/Name"
```

am use the Nginx-rtmp module to run it using the exec_static Directive 
but i can't monitoring every channels or process, can't stop start restart edit any stream without stop all channels

any idea Please?

Best,

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like (this is in PHP but you can use similar procedure from other scripts):

```
                    $cmd = "ps aux | grep '-vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv'";
                    exec($cmd, $output, $returnvalue);

                    $transcoders = 0;
                    foreach ($output as $line) if (strstr($line, "ffmpeg"))
                        {
                            $columns = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);

                            if ($kill) //customise this to kill a process
                            {
                                $kcmd = 'kill -KILL ' . $columns[1];
                                exec($kcmd, $koutput, $kreturnvalue);
                            }
                         }
```

Functionality is inspired from a [WP Videochat Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ppv-live-webcams/) that has a backend section for monitoring and killing FFMPEG processes (used for transcoding live streams for HLS playback and generating snapshots from streams).